# Angles and tangents finding specific points

Tags: calculus

Find any points on the graph $y=x^3$ where the tangent makes an angle of $45$ degrees with the $x$ axis  in the positive direction

I don't understand the $45$ degree bit, I differentiated but I'm stuck upon what to do next, thanks

Comment: A line with a 45 degree angle from the x axis is just a line with slope of 1.  (because tan(45)=1)

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x^3\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2$$

We want to find all the points where the tangent to the graph has an angle $\theta = 45^\circ$ i.e. $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan\theta = \tan45^\circ=1$

So we set $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$

$$3x^2=1\implies x^2=\frac{1}{3}\implies x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Then we compute $y=\pm \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$

So the coordinates of these points are:$\quad (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}),\quad(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}})$

This makes sense when you think about it, since $y(x)=-y(-x)\quad$ i.e. $y(x)$ is an odd function

Answer (score 0):

if the tangent line makes an angle $45^\circ$ with the positive $x$-axis, then the slope of the line is $1.$ you find the derivative of $x^3$ and set it to $1.$ solve the resulting quadratic equation. you should get two solutions because the graph of $y = x^3$ is odd.